Updates made in the application pass only after restart php-FPM after enable opcache
I have enabled opcache in php.ini  but the updates made in the application pass only after restart php-FPM.
I have installed cachetool to manage cache, but even when I run those commands, updates are always not applied.
sudo php /usr/bin/cachetool.phar opcache:reset
sudo php /usr/bin/cachetool.phar opcache:reset --fcgi=/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock

sudo php /usr/bin/cachetool.phar apcu:cache:clear

Updates pass only when restart php-fpm
service php8.2-fpm restart

This is the config:
sudo php /usr/bin/cachetool.phar opcache:configuration

Zend OPcache 8.2.17
+---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Directive                             | Value                                        |
+---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| opcache.enable                        | true                                         |
| opcache.enable_cli                    | false                                        |
| opcache.use_cwd                       | true                                         |
| opcache.validate_timestamps           | false                                        |
| opcache.validate_permission           | false                                        |
| opcache.validate_root                 | false                                        |
| opcache.dups_fix                      | false                                        |
| opcache.revalidate_path               | true                                         |
| opcache.log_verbosity_level           | 1                                            |
| opcache.memory_consumption            | 268435456                                    |
| opcache.interned_strings_buffer       | 8                                            |
| opcache.max_accelerated_files         | 20000                                        |
| opcache.max_wasted_percentage         | 0.05                                         |
| opcache.consistency_checks            | 0                                            |
| opcache.force_restart_timeout         | 180                                          |
| opcache.revalidate_freq               | 2                                            |
| opcache.preferred_memory_model        | ''                                           |
| opcache.blacklist_filename            | ''                                           |
| opcache.max_file_size                 | 0                                            |
| opcache.error_log                     | ''                                           |
| opcache.protect_memory                | false                                        |
| opcache.save_comments                 | true                                         |
| opcache.record_warnings               | false                                        |
| opcache.enable_file_override          | false                                        |
| opcache.optimization_level            | 2147401727                                   |
| opcache.lockfile_path                 | '/tmp'                                       |
| opcache.file_cache                    | ''                                           |
| opcache.file_cache_only               | false                                        |
| opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks | true                                         |
| opcache.file_update_protection        | 2                                            |
| opcache.opt_debug_level               | 0                                            |
| opcache.restrict_api                  | ''                                           |
| opcache.huge_code_pages               | false                                        |
| opcache.preload                       | '/var/www/hostname/prod/config/preload.php' |
| opcache.preload_user                  | 'www-data'                                   |
| opcache.jit                           | ''                                           |
| opcache.jit_buffer_size               | 0                                            |
| opcache.jit_debug                     | 0                                            |
| opcache.jit_bisect_limit              | 0                                            |
| opcache.jit_blacklist_root_trace      | 16                                           |
| opcache.jit_blacklist_side_trace      | 8                                            |
| opcache.jit_hot_func                  | 127                                          |
| opcache.jit_hot_loop                  | 64                                           |
| opcache.jit_hot_return                | 8                                            |
| opcache.jit_hot_side_exit             | 8                                            |
| opcache.jit_max_exit_counters         | 8192                                         |
| opcache.jit_max_loop_unrolls          | 8                                            |
| opcache.jit_max_polymorphic_calls     | 2                                            |
| opcache.jit_max_recursive_calls       | 2                                            |
| opcache.jit_max_recursive_returns     | 2                                            |
| opcache.jit_max_root_traces           | 1024                                         |
| opcache.jit_max_side_traces           | 128                                          |
| opcache.jit_prof_threshold            | 0                                            |
+---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+


opcache.validate_timestamps : false - it's not checking the files have been updated. This is a good configuration if you do not change files on the server, only deploy new files (which should also be to a different filepath).

@AlisterBulman, I put it false because in the symfony documentation they said that for performance , what should I do please ?
https://symfony.com/doc/current/performance.html#don-t-check-php-files-timestamps

Try sudo php /usr/bin/cachetool.phar opcache:reset:file-cache --fcgi=/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock

@hous set it to true, which will impact performance, but allow the less-than-advisable thing that you want to do.
